# lm-sensors reporting negative temperature

Tags: monitoring, temperature, lm-sensors

I get the following output when running sensors on my Ubuntu 12.04 server

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:        -3.0°C  (crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:        +5.0°C  (crit = +90.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +54.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)
```

Obviously its incorrect, how do I fix it?

Comment: I'd recommend running **sensors-detect** again as root.

Comment: Try reducing the flow of liquid nitrogen.

Comment: sorry, no effect

Comment: Mine is reporting +27.8 and **-268.5**. :/

Answer (score -1):

You can fix it by unloading that module. It is obviously not available/connected.

I do not know what kind of server you have, but finding ISA adapters is highly unlikely in anything produced the last 10 years.

Comment: Its an ION330 ( http://www.asrock.com/nettop/NVIDIA/ION%20330/ )  What's the nouveau-pci-0100?

Comment: I also have an ISA adapter built into my Mini-ITX-board. See my own question for details http://superuser.com/questions/731570/lm-sensors-reporting-wrong-temperature-on-intel-atom-n270

Comment: @EthanLeroy: you probably have a module that uses an emulated ISA bus or similar, on a recent Mini-ITX board I can guarantee you that it's not a physical ISA bus.

Comment: @Wolph Maybe. But the software doesn't care if it's a real ISA bus or an emulated one.