# lm-sensors reporting wrong temperature on Intel Atom N270

Tags: linux, debian, temperature, intel-atom, lm-sensors

I have a Mini-ITX board with an onboard **Intel Atom N270**. It's a *fanless* system and getting very hot, so I want to monitor the temperature, but *lm-sensors* is always reporting the same values:

```
> sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1: +40.0°C  (crit = +75.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0: +33.0°C  (crit = +90.0°C)
```

In BIOS I can see the temperatures, but yeah, I want to monitor them while the system is running.

**Is lm-sensors the wrong tool for my system? Is there another, better tool for Debian?**

Maybe this helps?

```
> dmidecode -t 2
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.2 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 8 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: PhoenixAward
    Product Name: 945GSE-ITE8712
    Version: 6.0
```

Tell me, if you need more infos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sensors-detect` helped me finding the problem: The module `it87` wasn't loaded. So I ran `modprobe it87` which resulted in

```
ERROR: could not insert 'it87': Device or resource busy
```

Finally [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-fatal-error-inserting-it87-libmodules2-6-32-5-686kerneldrivershwmonit87-ko/) helped: I edited `/etc/default/grub` and added `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_enforce_resources=lax"
```

Then executed `update-grub`. Finally I had to add `it87` to `/etc/modules`, so that it gets loaded automatically on boot.

Reboot and now the output for `sensors` contains an additional section (but yes, the old sections and temperatures didn't change).

```
> sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +40.0°C  (crit = +75.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +24.0°C  (crit = +90.0°C)

it8712-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          +0.88 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in1:          +1.04 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in2:          +3.33 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in3:          +2.98 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in4:          +2.96 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in5:          +2.19 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in6:          +1.89 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in7:          +4.08 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)  ALARM
Vbat:         +3.17 V  
fan1:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 8)
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 8)
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 8)
temp1:        +52.0°C  (low  =  -1.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +21.0°C  (low  =  -1.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp3:        +46.0°C  (low  =  -1.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
cpu0_vid:    +2.050 V
intrusion0:  ALARM
```

`temp1` and `temp3` seem to report correct values. `temp2` flaps between -10 and 60°C